# Bootstrap 4 popover is not fixed on the map

Tags: openlayers, bootstrap-framework

I am using bootstrap 4 to   show some popovers on the points of the map, but they are not fixed, when you scroll the map the popover changes position.

In bootstrap 3 it works fine though. I don't know if there is any solution in OpenLayers to this.

https://jsfiddle.net/70p621w9/

Answer (score 1):

You can update the element’s popover, when the `moveend` event fires.

```
map.on("moveend", ()=>{
$(element).popover('update')
})
```